# Jquery validate is losing styles on submission

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate plugin, when the form is submitted, the styles are lost.

They just go whacky!

I'd like the form to stay the way it looks prior to submitting the form.

Attached is a screenshot and the code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<style>
.label {
  width:100px;
  text-align:right;
  float:left;
  padding-right:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#ats_fellow_application_payment_form label.error {
  color:#FB3A3A;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

#ats_fellow_application_payment_form input.error {
  color:#FB3A3A;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  color:#333;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='ats_fellow_application_payment_form']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
      lastname: "Please enter your lastname",

      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
</script>


<form  method="POST" name="ats_fellow_application_payment_form" id="ats_fellow_application_payment_form" novalidate="novalidate">   
    <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

[image: Before and After View of the Form]

Comment: I would assume this is caused by the error `label` elements the validate plugin adds. I'd suggest you look in the error customisation methods that the validate plugin allows you to use

Comment: The CSS code in your OP does NOT reproduce the issue you describe:  https://jsfiddle.net/j6v3x378/ ~ However, the jQuery Validate plugin does not affect CSS at all; it simply adds/removes classes and a `label` element for the error messages.  It's totally up to you to inspect your DOM and create the proper CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. This is a css issue. I would suggest removing the top/bottom padding on the label.error and either remove or update input.error. It would appear based on your images that there is additional styling being added to the error labels that is not included in the code you provided.

Alternatively, you could change the location of the error message by adding them to an error container using the errorContainer, errorLabelContainer and wrapper options of validate. You could also append your error message to an element to control styling and placement using:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.siblings('span.errorMsg'));
}
```

Additional information on these options can be found in the [docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t99xdsto/1/)

Comment: FYI - the OP's code works not much differently than yours:  https://jsfiddle.net/j6v3x378/ ~ The root of his issue lies within code he's failed to show us.